# Aplicar selected en un select con Razor

Tags: html, razor, html-select, cshtml

Tengo el siguiente código en un archivo con extensión cshtml:

```
@Html.DropDownList("TipoIdentificacionId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Con el cual cargo en un select un listado que proviene de base de datos, esto lo hace bien, pero quisiera saber si es posible con la misma sintaxis de razor aplicar el atributo selected de html a determinado option.

Comment: Puedes mostrar de que formas obtienes el listado con el que llenas el `DropDownList`?

Comment: El código del controlador encargado de llenar el DropDownList es el siguiente: TipoIdentificacionControlador controladorTipoIdentificacion = new TipoIdentificacionControlador();
            ViewBag.TipoIdentificacionId = new SelectList(controladorTipoIdentificacion.Seleccionar(), "Id", "Nombre");     El cual extrae los datos de un método llamado Seleccionar()

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer, sería asignar la propiedad `Selected` al item que vos pretendes desde el mismo `Controller`

Por ejemplo;

**Controlador**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Creo una lista de ejemplo
        List<SelectListItem> opciones = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem{ Text="Texto 1", Value="Value 1" },
            new SelectListItem{ Text="Texto 2", Value="Value 2" },
            new SelectListItem{ Text="Texto 3", Value="Value 3" },
            new SelectListItem{ Text="Texto 4", Value="Value 4" }
        };

        //Recorro la lista (que en tu caso vendría creada de otro lugar, asumo
        foreach(var opcion in opciones)
        {
            //Evalúo la condición que me llevaría a hacer que esa opción este seleccionada
            if (opcion.Text.Contains("4"))
            {
                //La selecciono
                opcion.Selected = true;
            }
        }
        //Por último la asigno a un ViewBag y retorno la vista
        ViewBag.opciones = opciones;

        return View();
    }
```

**Vista**

```
@Html.DropDownList("prueba",(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.opciones,null,null)
```

Y en caso de que uses el método fuertemente tipado

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.tu_variable, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.opciones,null,null)
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo eliminaría los `ViewBags` de mis trabajos y utilizaría `ViewModel` simplemente porque el desarrollo se vuelve mucho más **escalables** y fácil de mantener, por lo que empezaría creando un *ViewModel* con las propiedades que necesitas

```
public class SelectViewModel
{
   public int SelectedOption { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Lista { get; set; }
}
```

Y seguimos con la obtención de los datos y la selección de la opción por defecto que quieres mostrar:

```
public ActionResult MiAccion()
{
   List<SelectListItem>data = new List<SelectListItem>
   {
      new SelectListItem{ Text="Chile", Value = "1" },
      new SelectListItem{ Text="Argentina", Value = "2" },
      new SelectListItem{ Text="España", Value = "3" },
      new SelectListItem{ Text="Brasil", Value = "4" },
      new SelectListItem{ Text="Paraguay", Value = "5" },
      new SelectListItem{ Text="Colombia", Value = "6" },
      new SelectListItem{ Text="Ecuador", Value = "7" },
      new SelectListItem{ Text="Perú", Value = "8" },
      new SelectListItem{ Text="Venezuela", Value = "9" },
      new SelectListItem{ Text="Bolivia", Value = "10" }
   };

   string optionSelected = string.Empty;
   foreach (SelectListItem item in data)
   {
      if (item.Value == "6")
         optionSelected = item.Value;
   }

   SelectViewModel model = new SelectViewModel
   {
      SelectedOption = int.Parse(optionSelected),
      Lista = data.Select(x => new SelectListItem
      {
         Value = x.Value,
         Text = x.Text
      })
   };

   return View(model);
}
```

Y finalmente enlazamos el modelo a la vista con los datos:

```
@model SelectViewModel
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

@Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.SelectedOption, Model.Lista)
```

Te adjunto el resultado en .NET Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/yQtiUy

Answer (score 0):

el SelectList ya viene con un constructor en el que le pasas el valor del elemento seleccionado

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue);
```

De tal modo que en tu viewbag solo tienes que poner como parametro

```
ViewBag.TipoIdentificacionId = new SelectList(controladorTipoIdentificacion.Seleccionar(), "Id", "Nombre",opcionSeleccionada);
```

y el DropDownlist lo seleccionara en automatico al crear el option.

un ejemplo con un modelo propio

```
public int level_id { get; set; }
public int version_id { get; set; }
public SelectList LevelList { get; internal set; }
public SelectList VersionList { get; internal set; }

this.LevelList = new SelectList(new Repository<aql_levels>().Get().Select(x => new GeneralList(x)),"id","name", this.level_id);
this.VersionList = new SelectList(new Repository<aql_version>().Get().Select(x => new GeneralList(x)),"id","name", this.version_id);
```