# .Net dejar opcion de Combobox selecionada por defecto

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

Tengo un combobox que coge el DataSource de un Enum, el orden del enum no me gusta, pero no puedo modificar dicho enum, quisiera tener una opción (la tercera) preestablecida por defecto en el combobox. ¿Como podría hacerlo?

Terminé usando SelectedIndex para poner por defecto la que me interesa, pero ¿Cómo podría reorganizarlo?

Comment: Esta respuesta podría servir para tu caso amigo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/165054/aplicar-selected-en-un-select-con-razor/165085#165085

Comment: no le puedes asignar el selectedItem en codigo despues de el databind ?

Comment: No termino de entender la pregunta. Lo que quieres es que los elementos en el `Combobox` estén en el orden que tu quieres? Si es así, créate por ejemplo una lista, rellenala con los datos del Enum en el orden que quieras y pásale esa lista al combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola tienes que agregar la libería **System.Linq** para poder hacer un query sobre el ENUM

Lo primero en la instruccion obtiene los valores del Enum

```
(CType([Enum].GetValues(GetType(EnumParaCombo)), EnumParaCombo())).Select(Function(c) c.ToString)
```

y despues arreglamos el orden mediante la instrucción:

```
 OrderBy(Function(x) x).ToList
```

Te dejo el código de prueba que tiene un enum desordenado y al final lo imprime como una lista ordenada.

```
Imports System.Linq

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim enums As List(Of String) = (CType([Enum].GetValues(GetType(EnumParaCombo)), 
                                        EnumParaCombo())).Select(Function(c) c.ToString).
                                        OrderBy(Function(x) x).ToList

        For Each senum In enums
            Console.WriteLine(senum)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Enum EnumParaCombo
    OptionC = 0
    OptionA = 1
    OptionM = 2
    OptionF = 3
End Enum
```

El resultado de correr este programa es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende mucho tu pregunta, pero intenta así :

```
 Combobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```